# NSInvalidArgumentException with UITableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, compiler-errors

I'm building something of an information guide for class. I need to use UITableView, less this thing look like crap, so I've been working on it for about a week.

The error I receive is the NSInvalidArgumentException in the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
/*NSDictionary *dict = [_allPerks objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *temp = [dict objectForKey:@"Perks"];
return [temp count];*/
if (section == 0)
    return 9;
else if (section ==1)
    return 7;
else if (section ==2)
    return 11;
else if (section == 3)
    return 11;
else if (section == 4)
    return 8;
else
    return 0;

}
```

At least, I think it's there. The error states that my problem is in that function, something about it having an invalid sender. The code that is commented is my second attempt which didn't work.

This is a grouped table as well, just in case. I'm using an array of arrays to implement this, as there are a lot of elements I need to organize. If the code for that is necessary, just say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (section == 0){
          return 9;
    }
    else if (section ==1){
          return 7;
    } 
    else if (section ==2){
          return 11;
    }
    else if (section == 3){
          return 11;
    }
    else if (section == 4){
          return 8;
    }
    else{
          return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your method signature matches this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and not this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```